# PHP recursive function empty <ul></ul> issue

Tags: php, recursion

I am building recursive php menu function from database.

My connection:

```
 $menu = $vt->prepare("SELECT * FROM menus");
 $menu->execute(array());
 $menuSonuc = $menu->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

This function generating empty ul.

```
<li>
 <a href=""><span class="sagok"></span>TITLE</a>
 <ul></ul>
</li>
```

My Question:
How can I prevent empty ul in this function?

```
echo '<ul class="anamenu">';
           foreach ($menuSonuc as $menum) {




              if ($menum->katID == null) {

                 echo '<li><a href=""><span class="asagiok"></span>' . $menum->baslik . '</a>';
                 $id = $menum->id;
                 kategoriler($menuSonuc, $id);
                 echo '</li>';
              }
           }
           echo '</ul>';


           function kategoriler($menuSonuc, $id)
           {
              echo '<ul>';
              foreach ($menuSonuc as $menum) {
                 if ($menum->katID == $id) {
                    echo '<li><a href=""><span class="sagok"></span>' . $menum->baslik . '</a>';
                    kategoriler($menuSonuc, $menum->id);
                    echo '</li>';
                 }
              }
              echo '</ul>';
           }
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add some checks see the code below

```
    if(!empty($menuSonuc)){
    echo '<ul class="anamenu">';
           foreach ($menuSonuc as $menum) {




              if ($menum->katID == null) {

                 echo '<li><a href=""><span class="asagiok"></span>' . $menum->baslik . '</a>';
                 $id = $menum->id;
                 kategoriler($menuSonuc, $id);
                 echo '</li>';
              }
           }
    echo '</ul>';

}

function checkSub($menuSonuc, $id){
    foreach ($menuSonuc as $menum) {
         if ($menum->katID == $id) {
            return true;
         }
     }
     return false;
}
           function kategoriler($menuSonuc, $id)
           {
            if(!empty($menuSonuc)){
                  $index=0;
                  foreach ($menuSonuc as $menum) {
                     if ($menum->katID == $id) {
                        if($index==0){
                            echo '<ul>';
                        }
                        echo '<li><a href="">'.((checkSub($menuSonuc, $menum->id))?'<span class="sagok"></span>':''). $menum->baslik . '</a>';
                        kategoriler($menuSonuc, $menum->id);
                        echo '</li>';
                        $index++;
                     }
                  }
                  if($index>0){
                      echo '</ul>';
                  }

              }
           }
```

Comment: still getting empty <ul></ul>

Comment: It is now removed empty <ul></ul> thanks. Now how can I remove sagok class from span? it is a right arrow.

Comment: just  updated the answer added one more function for that

Comment: This is too work thanks, what about span class asagiok? it is down arrow icon, how can I remove asagiok from span?

Comment: it is also working like this:   echo '<li><a href="">'.((checkSub($menuSonuc, $menum->id))?'<span class="asagiok"></span>':''). $menum->baslik . '</a>';  correct?

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting empty `ul` it means that `$menuSonuc` is empty and it doesn't enter `foreach`. You can check if it is empty to prevent empty `ul`

```
function kategoriler($menuSonuc, $id){
if(empty($menuSonuc)){
    return;
}

echo '<ul>';
foreach ($menuSonuc as $menum) {
    if ($menum->katID == $id) {
        echo '<li><a href=""><span class="sagok"></span>' . $menum->baslik . '</a>';
        kategoriler($menuSonuc, $menum->id);
        echo '</li>';
    }
}
echo '</ul>';
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you are still getting an empty `ul` then the problem is in the condition that you are checking `$menum->katID == $id`.

That means that `$menum->katID` is never the same as `$id`.
Check these values and you will solve your problem. Or give us an example of your arrays so we can check them.

Comment: still getting empty <ul></ul>

Comment: You are getting just an empty <ul> or you are getting an empty ul inside other li? Please check my update